# Monotouch iPhone Project not appearing in MonoDevelop

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have just installed Mono 2.10.1_3, MonoDevelop 2.4.2, and MonoTouch 4.0.3.  In the order outlined on the website.  Now I am trying to walk through some of the tutorials for developing on the iPhone using MonoTouch.  However, I am stuck right at the start on the HelloWorld tutorial:

http://monotouch.net/Tutorials/MonoDevelop_HelloWorld

When creating a new solution and selecting C# then iPhone and iPad:

- iPhone Window-based Project
- iPhone OpenGL Project
- iPhone Navigation-based Project
- iPhone Utility Project
- MonoTouch Library Project
- Empty MonoTouch Project
- iPad Window-based Project
- Universal Window-based Project

There is no iPhone MonoTouch Project displayed in this list as shown in the Tutorial.  So I guess my question is this:  should there be an option for iPhone MonoTouch Project in the list or is this a newer version and this project template has been replaced by one of the options shown above?  If so, which one?

Comment: It seems that these are the new options for this version of MonoTouch.  I found this site: [knowing.net](http://www.knowing.net/index.php/monotouch-navigation-controller-tutorial/) and it shows the same options I am seeing in MonoDevelop.  It would appear the tutorial needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhone Window-based Project is your friend 
(it shows an small C# indicating the usage of MonoTouch)